# How do I select pins in Quartus 2?

Tags: cad, pins

I'm trying to complete homework with what appears to be a newer version of the software than what the instructions are for. It says in the instructions that I should select "pin" from the category option like this from the instructions
[image]

But my view doesn't look like that when I open the assignment editor in my Quartos 2 web edition:
[image]

What I'm supposed to do is add my input x1 to the "To" box and select a pin from a "location" option but it is not available. Can you tell me how I can select a pin for my compilation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Assignments->Pin planner.
Once in there, click on New Node, write the Node Name (same as port on topmost entity/module), and in Location you select the chip's pin number.  You can also select the kind of driver (ttl, cmos, etc) in that same table, along with other pin related settings, such as pullups and driver strength (if output).

If you already synthesized the design, the table will be already populated, so you just need to edit it with the desired locations, buffer type, drive strengths, etc.

Comment: It's a whole lot easier to complete the design first. Let the software do the work and populate the Pin Planner. From there, it's easy to fine tune and select pins.

Comment: The point was to have him use the pin planner, which he wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 2):

That is actually awkward method. First of all define all I/Os in top file and they will be displayed in Pin Planner. There You'll assign signals to physical pins.